# Dockerfile: QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device

Tags: linux, docker, build, dockerfile

I try to build an application inside a docker container.

If I build this image on my host, all goes well. If I push it to git, hub.docker shows the following error in the build log:

```
Step 12/22 : RUN qmake /opt/xflr5
---> Running in 026abab3988e
Info: creating stash file /opt/build/.qmake.stash
QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek: Cannot call seek on a sequential device
Removing intermediate container 026abab3988e
---> e032d94fd731
Step 13/22 : RUN make
---> Running in 69db13aebe2b
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -o xflr5 -L/usr/local/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [xflr5] Error 1
Makefile:235: recipe for target 'xflr5' failed
```

the corresponding Dockerfile can be find [here](https://github.com/Alex031544/docker_xflr5/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Why this happens at hub.docker and not at my host. And how can I resolve this?

Comment: @jww As the code is not from me, this may require a patch. But why this happens on docker hub and not on my host too? I even did not receive a warning on my host.

Comment: I apply a patch, which changes `seek` to `read`. `seek` occurs only once. But the error still exist on docker hub.

Comment: I stumbled on this because of a similar problem. qmake and lrelease run fine on fedora 31 docker image on the local machine, but fail with same docker image on  travis-ci. It works fine with a ubuntu bionic image. Qt version slightly differs. 5.12.2 on the working image, 5.12.4 on the failing image. Link: https://travis-ci.org/fritzing/fritzing-app/jobs/568022167

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/208

If you use GitLab you need to edit the file /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

```
[[runners]]  
  ...  
  [runners.docker]  
    ...  
    privileged = true  
    ...  
  [runners.cache]
```